# Cannot see private content

Tags: private

I have put all my pages private check and now I cannot access the wp-admin. Does anyone know how I can fix this from the database or from the WordPress code? I'm  the administrator.

Comment: Setting pages to private shouldn't have any effect on WP Admin, did you install a plugin to do this? When you say you cannot access `wp-admin` can you be more specific? White screen of death? Error message? User+pass no longer correct?

Comment: Thank you. Without installing any complement, I did it from the quick edition of each page by changing the visibility from public to private. When I enter my domain / wp-admin, says that the page does not exist. 
I am using woocommerce. Theme: Astra with Elementor.

Comment: I agree with Tom, there's nothing in what you did that should prevent access to the dashboard. Does `/wp-login.php` also show you a "page does not exist" error? Are you sure there aren't any typos? :)

Comment: Can you confirm `wp-admin/index.php` exists on your server?

Comment: Yes, wp-admin/index.php exists on my server.

Comment: An additional fact that may affect is that I am using woocommerce with access to wordpress, through my account page.

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution! I managed to solve the problem by changing the private post_status to publish in the wp_post table of the database. Thanks again!